# How to find/replace on a variable inside perl script

Tags: regex, perl, sed

In my perl script, I have a string variable which has '' in it. I have to replace it with a proper date like '20150101'. I tried the below but it expects the variable as file. Can you please point out what's wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $name="FILE_NAME_<DATE>.txt";
my $findDT="<DATE>";
my $dt="20150101";

my $realFileName=~`sed "s/$findDT/$dt/g" $name `;

print $name;
print $realFileName;
```

Comment: Ah, what a beautiful lack of `use strict; use warnings;` on this Wednesday morning.

Comment: ... I don't get why you are doing these things. Why have those extra varaibles? Why use break out to using a shell to run a sed command... that takes *Perl regex* when you using Perl already. Why even use Perl for this when you have the sed command to do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `sed`, which works on the content of a file. You can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name="FILE_NAME_<DATE>.txt";
my $findDT="<DATE>";
my $dt="20150101";

# First make a copy of your original variable
my $realFileName = $name;

# Then, replace the variable
$realFileName =~ s/$findDT/$dt/;

print "$name\n";
print "$realFileName\n";
```

As noted in a comment, remember to always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. They cost nothing and help a lot!

Comment: accidentally missed the 'use' statements in this test script. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you are using sed. Change your script to this.

> r  - perform non-destructive substitution and return the new value

Check [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name="FILE_NAME_<DATE>.txt";
my $findDT="<DATE>";
my $dt="20150101";

my $changedFileName = $name=~ s/$findDT/$dt/r;

print "Before Change: $name \n";
print "After Change: $changedFileName \n";
```

Comment: Agreed - Either use Perl or Unix Shell to do things like this - Not both.
Also, doing it in Perl will make it cross-platform and will run on Windows too.